# Backbone.sync and rpc

Tags: backbone.js

I like backbone very much, but I use not REST, but rpc over socket.io, so i need to customize somehow Backbone.sync logic, not to send RESTful requests, but to execute my client rpc library methods.

I found such example of `Backbone.sync` customization:
http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/4ArmM/

But not everything is clear for me. In the end Backbone.sync.call() is executed - what is it?
How does it really work? Does it just perform some GET request here, and i can just omit it (i do not have to make any requests as i am using socket), or it makes something important?

My idea is to take this example and just to insert here some rpc calls. Is it right way?

Comment: your example only override `sync` for `Backbone.Model` what you are looking for is `Backbone.sync`

Have a look at this: https://github.com/scttnlsn/backbone.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than start with an arbitrary fiddle, why not take a look at the Backbone [source code](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html). It's very easy to read and very well documented. Scroll down to the Backbone.Sync section and you'll find that it isn't very hard to override.